# How to add a gradient to an image

Tags: python, kivy

I have an interface made with Kivy, which has an image in part of it. I want to fade one edge of this image. What's the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried the example code on this page: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/kivy-users/Go7HINbBtI0/OSJvw0AEbPoJ ?

Comment: I've tried using the code that Tim H posts in that link, but it tells me it can't find the module, so I think I'm importing it incorrectly or from the wrong place. I'm not sure if that code gives me the ability to fade just the edge of an image though?

Comment: I guess the simplest way to do this in the kivy api is to use the Stencil instructions. You'd want to make a stencil mask whose own alpha fades at the edge. I'd have to experiment to see how this would work though, with the docs [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.stencil_instructions.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can just create another image with faded edge and load it.

Comment: I could just design the whole interface in Photoshop ;) The graphic is linked, and will change regularly unfortunately.